# Override components CSS once modal button is pressed?

Tags: css, reactjs, modal-dialog

I've currently got a modal set up, where once it's pressed, it opens a component of mine up. However, this component has a fixed css (which I want to keep), but when the modal is pressed, I want that CSS to change. Is this possible ? I've looked at a few things but can't seem to find something that works. What I've got currently can be seen below, and it doesn't override the original css.

```
  const [currentModal, openModal] = useState(null);
  const [appState, changeChange] = useState({
      activeObject: null,
      objects: [{id: 1}]
```

in the return

```
<div className="modal">
            {currentModal === 'modal1' ? 
              <MyComponent>  
              </MyComponent>
            : null}
          <div class="class1">

            {appState.objects.map((elements,index) => (
            <button key={index} classnName="box active"
             onClick={() => openModal('modal1')}>
              <Modal1></Modal1>
            </button>
             ))}
</div>
```

The  CSS

```
  .box{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:10px;
    transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in-out;
  }

  .inactive{
    background-color:pink;
  }
  .active {
    background-color: blue;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:10px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use styled components: https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props

Just pass a prop to the styled component wrapping your model. this prop will indicate if the modal has been pressed or not.

You'll have to change the css according to the prop value.